# How can I launch a new Activity to a Fragment that is not the initial fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

How can I launch a new Activity to a Fragment that is not the initial fragment? For example, the following code is wrong. I want to launch the MainActivity.class AT the SecondFragment.class. Seems simple enough but cannot find an answer anywhere. All help is greatly appreciated!

```
public void LaunchSecondFragment(View view) {
    view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.image_click));

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondFragment.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: so you want to launch MainActivity _from_ SecondFragment, right? Because your code looks like you want to launch SecondFragment, and if this is the case, then you should know that Fragments are not usually initiated via intents, you have to use FragmentManager instead.

Comment: Okay so my MainActivity is not the first activity that the user sees. Let's just call this initial activity FeedActivity. The user clicks a button that launches it into MainActivity (FirstFragment), but I want it to launch directly to SecondFragment. Does that make sense?

Comment: Come on man. Make it a little more English... :(

Comment: lol I'm trying my best. My MainActivity has 4 fragments. I want to launch _into_ the MainActivity directly to SecondFragment. How can I specify which fragment the MainActivity should open to upon launching?

Comment: Okay, i guess I know what you mean. So your MainActivity launches FirstFragment by default and you want it to launch SecondFragment in case it is called from a button in another acitvity? Well, you can put an extra in your intent intent.putExtra() and get it in activity onCreate method. And make some if/else the like if(getExtra == something) launch SecondFragment; else launch FirstFragment

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. I've heard the putExtra() term before, but haven't seen a working implementation. I'll try a few things out but if you have an answer would love to see one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, before starting an activity you have to do something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("launchSecondFragment", true)
startActivity(intent)
```

and in your MainActivity onCreate()

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("launchSecondFragment", false)) {
//do fragment transaction to second fragment
} else {
//do fragment transaction to the first fragment
}
```

**UPDATE**

So, here is the clever way to do it.

First of all create enum in your MainActivity.class

```
public enum FragmentNames {
FIRST_FRAGMENT,
SECOND_FRAGMENT
}
```

then define a string constant for getting and putting this extra(also in MainActivity)

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_EXTRA = "fragmentExtra";
```

So now when you start an activity you should do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_EXTRA, MainActivity.FragmentNames.SECOND_FRAGMENT);
startActivity(intent);
```

And catch in your MainActivity onCreate() method:

```
FragmentNames name = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(FRAGMENT_EXTRA);
switch(name) {
case FIRST_FRAGMENT:
//do stuff
break;
case SECOND_FRAGMENT:
//do stuff
break;
default:
//load default fragment(FirstFragment for example)
}
```

What else is cool about enums? You mentioned that you are using this intents to define current item of your ViewPager. Well, good news, enums have ordinal().

Basically you can do something like:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(name.ordinal());
```

In this case ordinal() of the FIRST_FRAGMENT is 0 and ordinal of SECOND_FRAGMENT is 1.

Just don't forget to check for nulls :)

Cheers.

Comment: This answer worked beautifully. Very easy to implement. In my case I simply set the currentItem in my mViewPager to the number of the fragment I wanted to access, i.e. mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); where 1 is the "second" fragment and 0 is the "first". I put this line where your comment "//do fragment transaction to second fragment" is located. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. This pattern is okay if you are dealing with not complicated logic. If you want to implement something more neat, you'd better use switch-case like @Niko Yowono suggested. I will update my answer in a bit to show you, how I would do it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That makes a lot of sense, and clears up many concepts surrounding fragments I wasn't aware of. P.S. Do you think you could up-vote my question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);   
int fragmentIndex = 2;
intent.putExtra("fragment_index", fragmentIndex);
startActivity(intent);
```

and this for the MainActivity's onCreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int fragmentIndex;
if(extras != null) {
    fragmentIndex = extras.getInt("fragment_index",1);
}
switch(fragmentIndex) {
    case 1:
        //display fragment 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //display fragment 2
        break;
    case 3:
        //display fragment 3
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks button and your `MainActivity` opens, its `onCreate()` will be get called.

You should add fragment transaction in `onCreate()` to launch `SecondFragment` :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFragment);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```